# Assigning results to textbox after finish barcode scanning

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

I am trying to assign the result from barcode scanning to a text box in angular, but I am unable to do that. Can anyone please help?

controller.js

```
this.formData = {};
this.formData.rawRecipient = "";
$scope.scanBarcode = function() {
            $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
                alert(imageData.text);
                var jsonon = JSON.parse(imageData.text);
                address = JSON.stringify(jsonon.data.addr);
                this.formData.rawRecipient = address;

            }, function(error) {
                alert("An error happened -> " + error);
            });
        };
```

html

```
<label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
  <span class="input-label">To</span>
     <input type="text" placeholder="{{'FORM_INVOICE_RECIPIENT_PLACEHOLDER' | translate}}" ng-model="$ctrl.formData.rawRecipient"/>
</label>
```

Comment: You can get text in alert?

Comment: @PareshGami yes I can

Comment: Your controller is access using this?